# How to create and reference "Theorem A1", "Theorem A2", "Theorem B1", etc

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems

I want to create two theorem styles of the following form:
Theorem A1
[Insert Theorem Here]

Theorem A2
[Insert Theorem Here]

Theorem B1
[Insert Theorem Here]

Theorem B2
[Insert Theorem Here]

and so on.  It is fairly straightforward to do this using `\newtheorem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}{4mm}{1mm}{\itshape}{ }{\bfseries}{.}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theoremA}{Theorem A\ignorespaces}
\newtheorem{theoremB}{Theorem B\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}

\begin{theoremA}\label{thm:A1}
This is a theorem of type A.
\end{theoremA}

\begin{theoremA}\label{thm:A2}
This is another theorem of type A.
\end{theoremA}

\begin{theoremB}\label{thm:B1}
This is a theorem of type B.
\end{theoremB}

\begin{theoremB}\label{thm:B2}
This is another theorem of type B.
\end{theoremB}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

> **Theorem A1.** *This is a theorem of type A.*
>
> **Theorem A2.** *This is another theorem of type A.*
>
> **Theorem B1.** *This is a theorem of type B.*
>
> **Theorem B2.** *This is another theorem of type B.*

So the code returns my desired result.  A problem, however, occurs when I attempt to cross-reference one of the theorems.  For example, if I site Theorem A1 using

> Theorem `\ref{thm:A1}`

returns

> Theorem 1

rather than `Theorem A1`.  Does anyone have an idea of how to correctly cross-reference a theorem in this form?  Is it possible to give the theorem a name, which is not displayed, so that I can use the command `\nameref{thm:A1}`?  A quick and dirty fix is

> Theorem A`\ref{thm:A1}`

but, using the `hyperref` package, a red box appears around the number "1" only.  I would prefer a red box around the entire expression "Theorem A1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The letter should be part of the counter's representation. Do like

```
\newtheorem{theoremA}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thetheoremA}{A\arabic{theoremA}}
\newtheorem{theoremB}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thetheoremB}{B\arabic{theoremB}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  Extending your answer, if one wants a red hyperef box around "Theorem A1" rather than just "A1", the following seems to work:

`\newtheorem{theoremC}{}
\renewcommand{\thetheoremC}{Theorem C\arabic{theoremC}}`

Comment: @MattT I'd not recommend this, as you'll get Theorem also at every `\ref`

Comment: [Slightly off-topic] @MattT: use `\newcommand*{\thmref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Theorem~\ref*{#1}}}` if you want such behaviour. I hope that's more what you'd also recommend @egreg (at least I use it like this).

Comment: @MattT Have a look at the `cleveref` package.